# Chat application with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, server, cloud

I am building a chat application but as a beginner I am confused and I am facing bunch of problems:-

1) The first problem that I am facing is that should i use firebase or not?

2) If yes, than I want all the data on my godaddy server, so is that possible like if user send some message than i want firebase to react but it should also make an entry on my mysql database on my server.

Comment: if you want to duplicate the data on your own mysql, you will have to support that separately. firebase runs off of its own real-time db

Answer (score 0):

1) Firebase is very powerfull to my mind. Firebase It frees us from having to handle many tasks, their database in real time is ideal for a chat.

2) It is possible, you can do from your Android device or from your server.

- From Android, every time you write something to the Firebase database, do you communicate with your server.
- From the server, simply having reference to the list that have chat messages in Firebase, add un EventListener and whenever there is a change in that list, Firebase notify your server and you do what you want.

A example of a chat using the last version of Firebase.

[Android Chat Firebase](https://github.com/ykro/android-chat-firebase)

Comment: Can you suggest a tutorial for this?

Comment: That's a pretty outdated sample app. For an up to date tutorial, have a look at the [Android codelab on the Firebase site](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android).